# Why this protected member is not visible in the subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

I have a problem understanding protected members inheritance and visibility.

I know it is visible in the same package and subclasses.

But in the following code it is not visible in a subclass.

A.java

```
package a;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    protected void run() {

    }
}
```

B.java

```
package b;

import a.A;

public class B extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.run(); // this works fine
    }
}
```

C.java

```
package b;
import a.A;

public class C extends A{ // it will not work also if extends B
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.run(); // this is the problem; not visible
    }
}
```

Why b.run() in the last class is invisible?

Comment: What is the access modifier of `run()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because class `C` can see `A`'s protected methods from within its ***own*** inheritance tree.  But it's not allowed to access `A`'s protected methods for ***another*** class (`B`) from a different inheritance tree.  `C` is not part of `B`'s inheritance tree (by this, I mean that's it's not a parent of `B`), therefore the behavior is normal.

**EDIT: Added documentation reference as requested**

[6.6.2.1. Access to a protected Member](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2):

> If the access is by a field access expression `E.Id`, or a **method invocation expression `E.Id(...)`**, or a method reference expression `E :: Id`, where `E` is a Primary expression (`§15.8`), then **the access is permitted if and only if the type of `E` is `S` or a subclass of `S`**.

Applying the above to this case, because the variable `b` is ***not*** an instance of `C` or a subclass of `C`, access to the protected method `b.run()` is not allowed.

Also addressing `Codebender`'s comment about the packages. Note that, if the `C` class would have been defined in the same package as the `A` class, where the protected `run()` method is defined, then the above rule wouldn't apply, and you would be able to access the method as shown in your code.

Comment: Can you put an official doc link explaining this? Since B and C are in the same package, and protected fields can be accessed in the same package, this seems a bit weird.

Comment: What about C extends B. It is the same problem.

Comment: Added more specific details from the documentation. Should clarify things for you hopefully.